# How do I add weighting to a curve not the data points during fitting? What import/func do I use?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft, curve-fitting, least-squares

I've tried scipy.optimize import curve_fit but it only seems to change the data points. I want to add a 1/Y^2 weighting during the fitting of the Ycurve from my data points residuals (least sq with weighting). I'm not sure how to target the yfit instead of ydata or if I should use something else? Any help would be appreciated.

````
xdata = np.array([0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 2.89, 2.89, 2.89, 2.89,
                     2.89, 2.89, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 23.30, 23.30, 23.30, 23.30, 23.30, 23.30, 108.98, 108.98,
                     108.98, 108.98, 108.98, 255.33, 255.33, 255.33, 255.33, 255.33, 255.33, 1188.62, 1188.62, 1188.62,
                     1188.62, 1188.62], dtype=float)

ydata = np.array([0.264352, 0.412386, 0.231238, 0.483558, 0.613206, 0.728528, -1.15391, -1.46504, -0.942926,
                     -2.12808, -2.90962, -1.51093, -3.09798, -5.08591, -4.75703, -4.91317, -5.1966, -4.04019, -13.8455,
                     -16.9911, -11.0881, -10.6453, -15.1288, -52.4669, -68.2344, -74.7673, -70.2025, -65.8181, -55.7344,
                     -271.286, -329.521, -436.097, -654.034, -396.45, -826.195, -1084.43, -984.344, -1124.8, -1076.27,
                     -1072.03, -3968.22, -3114.46, -3771.61, -2805.4, -4078.05], dtype=float)

def fourPL(x, A, B, C, D):
    return ((A-D)/(1.0+((x/C)**B))) + D

params, params_covariance = spo.curve_fit(fourPL, xdata, ydata)
params_list = params
roundy = [round(num, 4) for num in params_list]
print(roundy)

popt2, pcov2 = spo.curve_fit(fourPL, xdata, ydata, sigma=1/ydata**2, absolute_sigma=True)
yfit2 = fourPL(xdata, *popt2)
params_list2 = popt2
roundy2 = [round(num, 4) for num in params_list2]
print(roundy2)

x_min, x_max = np.amin(xdata), np.amax(xdata)
xs = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 1000)
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xs, fourPL(xs, *params), 'm--', label='No Weight')
plt.plot(xs, fourPL(xs, *popt2), 'b--', label='Weights')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05, 0.1, 0.1),
              ncol=3, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.xlabel('µg/mL)')
plt.ylabel('kHz/s')
#plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```
````

Comment: You can always use `least_squares`. Here you actually have to write your own residual function. This makes it easy, hence, to implement your own weighting.

Comment: Yes! This is what I started to realise about the curve.fit function and I definitely do not want to try writing my own residual function. Do you know which rho I should use/modify or can I can simply define it to 1/Y^2 on yfit? I see a lot of xs = x / x_scale but there doesn't appear something similar for y

Comment: Hi, the residual function sounds more complicated than it actually is. There are plenty of examples: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44805318/803359) is one and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51891284/803359) another one that includes weights. In the latter case provided externally, but calculating them internally from the function values would be even easier.

Comment: Can you explain in the second example how it would be calculated internally by a function? Is it not happening within the residual func?
 ```def residuals( parameters, fixpoint, data, weights=None ):
    theta, phi = parameters
    x0, y0, z0 = fixpoint
    if weights is None:
        w = np.ones( len( data ) )
    else:
        w = np.array( weights )
    diff = np.array( [ point_to_line_distance( x , y, z , theta, phi , *fixpoint ) for x, y, z in data ] )
    diff = diff * w
    return diff
```
Would I be looking to do same thing without z axis and diff = diff 1/w**2?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance thus far. Could you break down the example for me to process I'm struggling to interpret the the source code with zaxis and fixed point variables. I really want to try solve this because all my model outputs are off from the values I'm expecting to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my version using a manual `least_squares` fit. I compare it to the solution obtained with the simple `curve_fit`. Actually the difference is not very big and the `curve_fit` result looks good to me.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

np.set_printoptions( linewidth=250, precision=2 )  ## avoids OPs "roundy"

xdata = np.array(
    [
        0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 
        1.12, 1.12, 2.89, 2.89, 2.89, 2.89, 2.89, 2.89, 6.19, 6.19, 
        6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 23.30, 23.30, 23.30, 23.30, 23.30, 23.30,
        108.98, 108.98, 108.98, 108.98, 108.98, 255.33, 255.33, 255.33,
        255.33, 255.33, 255.33, 1188.62, 1188.62, 1188.62, 1188.62,
        1188.62
    ], dtype=float
)

ydata = np.array(
    [
        0.264352, 0.412386, 0.231238, 0.483558, 0.613206, 0.728528,
        -1.15391, -1.46504, -0.942926, -2.12808, -2.90962, -1.51093,
        -3.09798, -5.08591, -4.75703, -4.91317, -5.1966, -4.04019,
        -13.8455, -16.9911, -11.0881, -10.6453, -15.1288, -52.4669,
        -68.2344, -74.7673, -70.2025, -65.8181, -55.7344, -271.286,
        -329.521, -436.097, -654.034, -396.45, -826.195, -1084.43,
        -984.344, -1124.8, -1076.27, -1072.03, -3968.22, -3114.46,
        -3771.61, -2805.4, -4078.05
    ], dtype=float
)

def fourPL( x, a, b, c, d ):
    out = ( a - d ) / ( 1 + ( x / c )**b ) + d
    return out

def residuals( params, xlist, ylist ):
    # ~a, b, c, d = params
    yth = np.fromiter( (fourPL( x, *params ) for x in xlist ), np.float )
    diff = np.subtract( yth, ylist )
    weights = 1 / np.abs( yth )**1
    ## not sure if this makes sense, but we weigth with function value
    ## here I put it inverse linear as it gets squared in the chi-square
    ## but other weighting may be required
    return diff * weights

### for initial guess
xl = np.linspace( .1, 1200, 150 )
yl0 = np.fromiter( (fourPL( x, 1, 1, 1000, -6000) for x in xl ), np.float )

### standard curve_fit
cfsol, _ = curve_fit( fourPL, xdata, ydata, p0=( 1, 1, 1000, -6000 ) )
print( cfsol )
yl1 = np.fromiter( (fourPL( x, *cfsol ) for x in xl ), np.float )

### least square with manual residual function including "unusual" weighting
lssol = least_squares( residuals, x0=( 1, 1, 1000, -6000 ), args=( xdata, ydata ) )
print( lssol.x )
yl2 = np.fromiter( (fourPL( x, *( lssol.x ) ) for x in xl ), np.float )

### plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.scatter( xdata, ydata )
ax.plot( xl, yl1 )
ax.plot( xl, yl2 )

plt.show()
```

[image: two fit variants]

Looking at the covariance matrix, not only reveals rather large errors, but also quite high correlation of the parameters. This is due to the nature of the model of course, but should be handled with care, especially when it comes to data interpretation.

The problem becomes even more obvious when we only consider data  for small `x`. The data for large `x` scatters a lot anyhow. For small `x` or large `c` the Taylor expansion is `(a - d ) (1 - b x / c ) + d` which is`a - (a - d ) b / c x` and that is basically `a + e x`. So `b`, `c` and `d` are basically doing the same.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you!!  I can build from this example and adjust weighting to get the expected values graphpad is returning. I hope anyways 

Bottom: -7902, Top: 0.5633, IC50: 1371, Hillslope:- 1.163

Comment: How do you come up with 1, 1, 1000, -6000 as your initial guess, what is the reasoning behind these values and is it not okay to use min/max of y data and its mid point?

Comment: That was an educated guess. I wasn't sure about `a`. First guess was `c`: this is a bell-shape, and everything happens between `0` and `1200`. so I thought it would be a good idea to re-scale `x` by `1000`. It is not at its bottom yet, so `d` should be less than `-4000`. On `b` I wasn't sure either, so I kept `a` and `b` as `1`.  I visually checked with `yl0`. I am sure with some extra thought, one could come up with a reasonable way of automating a good guess ( in case that there are more data sets to come). Cheers